# Maximum Likelihood Estimation question - minimum log likelihood

Tags: machine-learning, maximum-likelihood

I know the formula for the likelihood of some parameters given the data. The result has to be maximised and I can avoid multiplication using the log. How can I make this a minimisation problem (i.e. rewrite the given formula). I presume it is not as easy as taking the negative log and than adding things - or is it? Thanks.

Christian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is that simple. If you you want to maximize $\log(L)$ but you have a computational routine that minimizes a function, you can minimize $-\log(L)$.